# Add another json object in each json object inside json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts

Hi I am new to Highchart, javascript, jquery,html, json array, json object I am trying to add another json object to each json object inside json array is it possible to do that in javascript using push? anyone can guide me I will really appreciate thank you

Current  jsonArray  with json object inside

```
[{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
    name: 'Test1',
    id: 'Test1',
    data: [10, 10]
},{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
    name: 'Test2',
    id: 'Test2',
    data: [120, 120]
},{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
    name: 'Test3',
    id: 'Test3',
    data: [320, 120]
}]
```

I want to add this in each json object inside jsonarray

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function () {
        return this.series.name + '<br/><span style="color:#273c75"><b> Amount : </b> </span>$' + this.y.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
}
```

Expected Output

```
[{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
    name: 'Test1',
    id: 'Test1',
    data: [10, 10],tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function () {
            return this.series.name + '<br/><span style="color:#273c75"><b> Amount : </b> </span>$' + this.y.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
    }
},{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
    name: 'Test2',
    id: 'Test2',
    data: [120, 120],tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function () {
            return this.series.name + '<br/><span style="color:#273c75"><b> Amount : </b> </span>$' + this.y.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
    }
},{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
    name: 'Test3',
    id: 'Test3',
    data: [320, 120],tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function () {
            return this.series.name + '<br/><span style="color:#273c75"><b> Amount : </b> </span>$' + this.y.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming your array of objects is called `array`, you simply do this:

```
var tooltip = {
   pointFormatter: function () {
       return this.series.name + '<br/><span style="color:#273c75"><b> Amount : </b> </span>$' + this.y.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
   }
}

array.forEach(function(item) {
    item.tooltip = tooltip;
});
```

This way, every object in the array will be modified. However, be wary of this, I don't know exactly how do you use the `pointFormatter` function, but unless you call it using `apply` or `call`, the `this` variable inside it will be an alias of the global namespace, not a specific object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this is `JSON`, firstly do `JSON.parse(data)` and get normal js array, then
use javascript [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. Example code

```js
const exampleArray = JSON.parse(data);
const result = exampleArray.map(item => {
                 return {
                 ... item,
                 tooltip: {
                        pointFormatter: function () {
                            return this.series.name + '<br/><span style="color:#273c75"> 
                          <b> Amount : </b> </span>$' + 
                          this.y.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, 
                            ",");
                        }
                    }
};
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply traverse the array and define a property for each entry. Using the dot operator on a non-existing property in the object will create one. If it exists, it will simply override it.

Here is how:

```
// 1. Define your list/array
var myList = [{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
                name: 'Test1',
                id: 'Test1',
                data: [10, 10]
            },{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
                name: 'Test2',
                id: 'Test2',
                data: [120, 120]
            },{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
                name: 'Test3',
                id: 'Test3',
                data: [320, 120]
            }];
// 2. Traverse the list and define the value of the new property.
for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {

    myList[i].tooltip = function () {
                            console.log("insert my code here...");
                        }
}

// 3. Execute the function for the first list entry
this.myList[0].tooltip()
```

For the series name, I'm not sure where that property is, but this might be the thing that you were looking for:

```
// 1. Define your list/array
var myList = [{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
                name: 'Test1',
                id: 'Test1',
                data: [10, 10]
            },{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
                name: 'Test2',
                id: 'Test2',
                data: [120, 120]
            },{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
                name: 'Test3',
                id: 'Test3',
                data: [320, 120]
            }];
// 2. Traverse the list and define the value of the new property.
for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {

    myList[i].tooltip = function () {
                                return this.name + '<br/><span style="color:#273c75"><b> Amount : </b> </span>$' + this.data[0].toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");}
}

// 3. Execute the function for the first list entry
this.myList[0].tooltip()
```

*Why should we not use array push?*

You gotta define what you want and what you actually want to do is modify existing entries of the array and not add new entries. Push adds new elements/entries at the end of the array. So, what you actually want to do is add a property to the entries/array elements rather than adding a new element to the list.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and great explanation

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet for you.

```js
const initData = [{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
    name: 'Test1',
    id: 'Test1',
    data: [10, 10]
},{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
    name: 'Test2',
    id: 'Test2',
    data: [120, 120]
},{showInLegend: false, type: 'column',
    name: 'Test3',
    id: 'Test3',
    data: [320, 120]
}];

const pointerObj = function () {
        return this.series.name + '<br/><span style="color:#273c75"><b> Amount : </b> </span>$' + this.y.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};


const newData = initData.map(data => {
  return { ...data, tooltip: {
    pointer: function () {
        return this.series.name + '<br/><span style="color:#273c75"><b> Amount : </b> </span>$' + this.y.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
  }}
});

console.log("New Data", newData);
```